# Can I re-enter the US with 1 month validity

Tags: passport-stamps, h1b-visas

I have a new passport and the H1b visa stamp in my old passport expires on Aug 21. I have a valid I-797 till Dec 22. Can I travel outside the US and return in July without getting a new visa stamp or will I need to get a new stamp before re-entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A US visa's expiration date means the last day on which you can use that visa to enter the US. Since your visa expires August 21, yes, you can use it to enter the US in July; you can even use it to enter the US on the expiration date of August 21 itself. When you enter the US, you should be admitted until the expiration of your H1b petition. If you bring your latest H1b petition approval notice, you should be admitted until December 22.